# lightning:inputAddress field value access

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I have lightning component with lightning:inputAddress field and i need to access value of Address fields entered by user like Street, City etc.
How can i access it?

below is my sample code:

## Mark Up

```
   <aura:component controller="accountDataController" >
   <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" access="global"/>
   <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account" default="{sobjectType : 'Account'}" />
   <aura:handler event="c:billingEvent" action="{!c.doInit}" />
   <lightning:tabset >
    <lightning:tab >            
      <aura:set attribute="label">                                                  
       Address
      </aura:set>
     <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="1" smallDeviceSize="3" mediumDeviceSize="6">        
            <lightning:inputAddress
                aura:id="billingAddress"
                addressLabel="Billing Address"
                streetLabel="Street"
                cityLabel="City"
                countryLabel="Country"
                provinceLabel="Province/State"
                postalCodeLabel="PostalCode"
                street="{!v.account.BillingStreet}"
                city="{!v.account.BillingCity}"
                province="{!v.account.BillingState}"
                country="{!v.account.BillingCountry}"
                postalCode="{!v.account.BillingPostalCode}"                     
            />
           </lightning:layoutItem>
         </lightning:layout>
         </lightning:tab>
    </lightning:tabset>

   <lightning:button label="Next" onclick="{!c.goNext}" />   
  </aura:component>
```

## Controller

```
    ({
       doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAccount");

        action.setParams({"accountId": params.accountID});

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.account", response.getReturnValue());
            } else {
                console.log('Problem getting getBillingInfo, response state: ' + state);
            } 
        });            

        $A.enqueueAction(action);

       },
       goNext : function(component, event, helper) {
           //needs to access address values here.
       }
    })
```

## Apex Controller

```
public with sharing class accountDataController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account getAccount(Id accountId) {

        System.debug('Account ID = ' + accountId);

        String actQuery = 'SELECT id, AccountNumber, Name, Customer_Segment__c, Customer_Type__c, Customer_Sub_Type__c, ' +
                            'Sales_Channel__c, Market_Segment__c, Selling_Company__c,   Line_of_Business__c, Legal_Entity__c, ' +
                            'Currency__c, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry, '+
                            'ShippingStreet, ShippingCity, ShippingState, ShippingPostalCode, ShippingCountry '+
                             'FROM Account WHERE Id =  \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(accountId)+ '\'';

        system.debug('getAccount Query = ' + actQuery);

        Account act = Database.query(actQuery);

        return act;        
    }
}
```

How can i access Address Fields value in Client Controller

Comment: Did you try `component.get("v.account.BillingCity");`

Comment: The problem with that is, it will give apex side information, but if customer enter information in the form that will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are binding your account Record attribute in `lightning:inputAddress`. If the user changes anything, it will automatically change the value in the account Record attribute. So, you can get Billing City value by `component.get("v.account.BillingCity");`.

If you don't want to bind your account record attribute, You can access values of Address fields by the following way.

component:

`<lightning:inputAddress
     aura:id="billingAddress" 
     addressLabel="Billing Address"
     streetLabel="Street"
     cityLabel="City"
     countryLabel="Country"
     provinceLabel="Province/State"
     postalCodeLabel="PostalCode"
     street=""
     city=""
     province=""
     country=""
     postalCode=""

  />`

Controller:

  `goNext : function(component, event, helper) {
       var inputAddress = component.find("billingAddress"); //finding Input Address by aura:id
       console.log('BillingCity', inputAddress.get("v.city"));
   }`

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, try using

```
 goNext : function(component, event, helper) {
       //needs to access address values here.
       alert(component.get('v.account.BillingCity'));
   }
```

This will give you the updated value what the user has entered and not the one which was fetched from the apex controller.